# Styling navigationBar but keeping navigationItem the default style

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self] autorelease];

nav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
nav.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(closeMe:)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
```

I want to give the look that there is only the Done button. The background to the view is black, so Ive styled the navigationBar to be black, but this also turns the Done button black, but I want to keep it Blue.

[image: Correct Button but has white gradient]
[image: No gradient but button is Black]